# Ember: transaction.commit does not fire after becameInvalid event

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember data with the REST adapter. When you save a record using this.transaction.commit() and the server responds with a 422 validation error, then this case can be captured using the "becameError" event.

However, after changing the data in teh form field and clicking save again (thus doing a second this.transaction.commit(), nothing happens.  The transaction is not committed because we are in a Invalid state ...

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After transition to ('loaded.created.uncommitted') state in case of a becameInvalid state, you need to use the **store defaultTransaction** to recommit.

See code below - very dirty check to know whether to use transaction.commit() or defaultTransaction.commit()

```
save: function () {

//Local commit - author record goes in Flight state
this.transaction.commit();

//After a becameInvalid state, transaction.commit() does not work; use defaultTransaction in that case
//Is this the only way to do this ?
if (this.get('stateManager.currentState.name') == "uncommitted") {
  this.get('store').get("defaultTransaction").commit();
}

var author = this.get('model');

author.one('didCreate', this, function () {
  this.transitionToRoute('author.edit', author);
});

//If response is error (e.g. REST API not accessible): becameError fires
author.one('becameError', this, function () {
  this.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted');
});

//If response is 422 (validation problem at server side): becameInvalid fires
author.one('becameInvalid', this, function () {
  this.set('errors', this.get('content.errors'));

  //Does set stateManager.currentState.name to uncommitted, but when committing again, nothing happens.  
  this.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted')
});
```

},

Answer (score 1):

You can transition the model back to uncommitted state via it's stateManager. If it is an existing record, transition to `loaded.updated.committed`:

```
model.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.updated.uncommitted')
```

and for new records, transition to `loaded.created.uncommitted`

```
model.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted')
```

Consider this to be a workaround until the ember-data API has a better way.

See [What can you do with Ember Data Models when in the error state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741377/what-can-you-do-with-ember-data-models-when-in-the-error-state?rq=1) and https://gist.github.com/intrica/4773420 for more detail

Comment: Mike, I tried your suggestion. At first sight it worked, but after some more testing, it seems that it only works for the becameError state.  I have posted another answer describing the problem.  In both becameError and becameInvalid states, calling transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted') results in the transaction becoming "uncommitted" - which is perfect.  But, when then committing again, only in the case of becameError, a commit is completed. In the case of becameInvalid, no commit is done. It looks like there is something else preventing the commit.

Comment: Just found that in case of becameInvalid, you need to use the defaultTransaction for the subsequent commit.  Looks very complicated and dirty code, but it works ...

Answer (score 0):

As a horrible workaround, you can try saving a clone of the record instead. This will leave your original record pristine.

If the save succeeds, delete the original record.
Else delete the clone and try again with a new clone.